# Trying to extract the substring of a string until the string's first number

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I am trying to extract the substring of a string until the string's first number.

```
var notes = ["D4", "F#8", "Abb2"];
note[0].substring(0,notes[0].indexOf(4);
```

//returns D, gets rid of 1

However, this only works if the first number is 4. Other items in my notes array have numbers that are different.

I've tried to modify my code so that the argument for indexOf is a regular expression, but it isn't working:

```
var reg = /^\d+$/;
notes[0].substring(0,notes[0].indexOf(reg));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the first part without number.

```js
function getNote(string) {
    return string.match(/^\D+/)[0];
}

var notes = ["D4", "F#8", "Abb2"];

console.log(notes.map(getNote));
```